# Returning from .filter nested within .ForEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, functional-programming

I have this code that i have been figuring out by trial and error:

```
let _fk = this.selectedIaReportDiscussedTopic$
        .map((discussionTopic) => {return discussionTopic.fk_surveyanswer}) //["string"]
        .forEach((fk) => { 
            let surveyAnswerMatches = this.surveyAnswers.filter((sa) => {
                return fk === sa._id
            })
            console.log('surveyAnswerMatches', surveyAnswerMatches)//[object] <- this contains what I want and so I return it below, but nothing shows in console.log(_fk)
            return surveyAnswerMatches
        })

    console.log('this is fk', _fk) //'undefined'
```

What I want, is to be able to access the surveyAnswerMatches array from outside of the function.  I thought returning the array would allow me to access it through the _fk variable.

How come the return value does not get assigned to _fk?

What would allow me to access the surveyAnswerMatches from out outside all the .forEach and .map calls?

Thanks SO community!

Edit: More Info

```
console.log('this.selectedIaReportDiscussedTopic$', this.selectedIaReportDiscussedTopic$) //[{_id: "discussed_topic_2016-11-03T11:48:48Z_1", fk_surveyanswer:"surveyanswer_2016-11-03T11:48:48Z_1" }]
let surveyAnswerMatches = this.selectedIaReportDiscussedTopic$
            .map((discussionTopic) => {return discussionTopic.fk_surveyanswer})
            .map((fk) => { 
                return this.surveyAnswers.filter((sa) => {
                    return fk === sa._id
                })
            });

   console.log('this is surveyAnswerMatches', surveyAnswerMatches)// This is what I get [[{_id:"surveyanswer_2016-11-03T11:48:48Z_1", foo: "someotherbar"}]]
   console.log('this.surveyAnswers', this.surveyAnswers)// [{_id:"surveyanswer_2016-11-02T13:29:26Z_1", foo: "bar"}, {_id:"surveyanswer_2016-11-02T15:34:41Z_1", foo: "somebar"},{_id:"surveyanswer_2016-11-03T11:48:48Z_1", foo: "someotherbar"}]
```

Comment: What is the overall goal of the code?

Comment: My goal is to return whats in the surveyAnswerMatches array. I have multiple state objects and I need to map between a number of them based on foreign_keys.

Comment: You want a single array of all the members of all the `surveyAnswerMatches` arrays? Or you want an Array of Arrays? If the former, use `.reduce()`. If the latter, use `.map()` as suggested by @T.J.Crowder below. If you only wanted the first `surveyAnswerMatches` array, use `.find()`. The answer depends on a clear explanation of the problem.

Comment: *"My goal is to return whats in the surveyAnswerMatches array."* Again, which one? In the above, there's one for **each call** to the callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I included more info in my question and also switched to using the .map method as you mentioned in your answer. I guess the reason I end up with an array of arrays is because I call .map().  If I wanted just an array of surveyanswers objects, I could use .concat(). I will try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a closure to access a variable you defined before calling the mapping and forEach:

```
let surveyAnswerMatches = [];    
this.selectedIaReportDiscussedTopic$
        .map((discussionTopic) => {return discussionTopic.fk_surveyanswer}) //["string"]
        .forEach((fk) => { 
            surveyAnswerMatches.push(this.surveyAnswers.filter((sa) => {
                return fk === sa._id;
            }));
        });

console.log('this is surveyAnswerMatches', surveyAnswerMatches);
```

**Edit**: cleaned up the code

Answer (score 1):

> How come the return value does not get assigned to _fk?

Because the return value of the callback you pass into [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) has absolutely nothing to do with what `forEach` returns (which is nothing, so using its return value gives you `undefined`).

You've said you want to use "the return value," but which one? The callback is called repeatedly, once for each entry in the array.

You could change your `forEach` to another `map`, which would mean you'd end up with an array containing the `surveyAnswerMatches` for each entry in the array.